# Woof Фильтр, убрать пустые термины

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

У меня  магазин футболок шапок и открыток на Wordpress-е, установлен Woof Products Filter.
Подскажите, пожалуйста: как скрыть пустые теги, то-есть пункты фильтра в которых количество товара равно 0?

Для наглядности даю ссылку на [сайт](http://new.yosyamitya.com/shop/?swoof=1&product_cat=futbolki).

Answer (score 1):

Можно написать скрипт который будет получать значение поля и сравнивать его с "(0)", и присваивает родительским li класс что их скрывает.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.woof_checkbox_count').each(function (index, value) { 
        if ($(this).html() == "(0)") {$(this).closest("li").addClass("hidden"); }}); }); </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Купить платную версию плагина, так как необходимая Вам опция в бесплатной версии отключена.

Comment: Это-то понятно, но мне кажется, что добиться цели не так уж и сложно, прописав необходимый скрипт. Вот только слаба я пока в реализации необходимого функционала, вроде как и понятно, что если в скобочках цифра "0", то это значение не показывать, а как правильно написать не знаю. По сему и спрашиваю.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.